# How to export EC2 EBS volume attached to an instance without mouting it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, ec2-api-tools

I am trying to export EBS volume. It is possible to do it by mounting it to an instance. but I want to export it without mounting. i.e direct export from EBS. Is it possible?
How can I do it.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to mount the volume to an instance, even a micro instance in order to gain access to it and its data. You cannot attach an EIP directly to an EBS and you need some type of internet gateway to move the data around.